# Error with npm install #7884 - npm WARN locking Error: EACCES

Tags: npm

trying npm install on concat-map i get this error i already tried adding sudo

```
npm install concat-map
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/mercadotecnia/.npm/_locks/concat-map-a127112b4f6ee84c.lock'
npm WARN locking  /Users/mercadotecnia/.npm/_locks/concat-map-a127112b4f6ee84c.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/mercadotecnia/.npm/_locks/concat-map-a127112b4f6ee84c.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: 3,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/mercadotecnia/.npm/_locks/concat-map-a127112b4f6ee84c.lock' }
npm ERR! Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "concat-map"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.0

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /Users/mercadotecnia/Desktop/Sitios/bill/node_modules/concat-map, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 1):

in terminal, do the following

> $ sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked for me, but really dont know what this command does... :)